# Why am I getting this strange routing error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, rails-routing

Why am I getting this strange routing error when I click the "Create Questions" button?

```
No route matches [POST] "/questions"
```

I have...

**/config/routes.rb**:

```
resources :questions, :only => [:index, :update, :destroy, :edit]
resources :products do
  resources :questions, :except => [:index, :update, :destroy, :edit]
end
```

**/app/controllers/questions_controller.rb**:

```
def new
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  session[:product] = @product.id
  @question = @product.questions.build
end

def create
  @product = Product.find(session[:product])
  flash[:notice] = "Question was successfully created." if @question = @product.questions.create(params[:question])
  respond_with @product, @question
end
```

**/app/views/questions/_form.html.haml**:

```
= simple_form_for @question do |f|
  = f.association :products, :label => "Products" unless @product.present?
  = f.button :submit, :id => 'submit_question'
```

I always access `questions#new` from `products#show`, so `@product.present?` is always true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the :create action in your routes:

```
resources :questions, :only => [:index, :update, :destroy, :edit, :create]
```

Comment: Isn't it implied in `resources :products do
  resources :questions`?

Comment: Your form is posting to `/questions`. With the above, you need to submit the form to `/:product_id/questions`...

Comment: About to this the "accept" tick when Stackoverflow lets me in a few minutes, but it's for the original suggestion of adding the :create route to `resources :questions`. (That solution lets me share a form partial between the edit and new methods.)